# Boost regex_match for string_ref

Tags: c++, boost

I am using boost::regex_match with boost::string_ref, but build failed due to template deduce error, how can I fix it?

```
 boost::smatch base;                                                                                                                      
  boost::string_ref sr = "4f000000-4f015000 r-xp 00000000 03:01 12845071   /lib/ld-2.3.2.so";                                              
  boost::regex                                                                                                                             
    re(R"(^([[:xdigit:]]+)-([[:xdigit:]]+)\s+..x.\s+([[:xdigit:]]+)\s+\S+:\S+\s+\d+\s+(\S+\.(so|dll|dylib|bundle)((\.\d+)+\w*(\.\d+){0,3})?)$)");                                                                                                                                     
  if (boost::regex_match(sr.cbegin(), sr.cend(), base, re)) {                                                                              
    std::cout << base[0] << std::endl;                                                                                                      
  }
```

The compiler error:

> /usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_match.hpp|44 col 6| note: candidate:
>   template bool boost::regex_match(BidiIterator, BidiIterator,
>   boost::match_results&, const
>   boost::basic_regex&,
>   boost::regex_constants::match_flag_type)
>   ||  bool regex_match(BidiIterator first, BidiIterator last,
>   ||       ^
>   /usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_match.hpp|44 col 6| note:   template
>   argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   regex.cpp|161 col 58| note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter
>   'Iterator' ('const char*' and '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`boost::smatch` is an alias to `match_results<std::string::const_iterator>`, so the solution:

```
boost::match_results<boost::string_ref::const_iterator> base;
```